# How to de-couple and do dependency injection with highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have two models: **iposectors**, and **ipomarketcap**, a **Factory** that creates an instance of the model depending on the parameter, and **BindingCode** that binds all together.
The models have hard-coded data for testing, but plan to retrieve data from API.
Here is the fiddle: [highcharts](https://jsfiddle.net/ksutine/hn6sevka/).

Nothing shows up...
When on the debugger line - I can see that the highchart object is created, and all data is attached, but only default title appears.
What am I missing?

```
        var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ["highcharts-ng"]);
    myapp.controller('myctrl', BindingCode);
    myapp.factory("Factory", Factory);

    function iposectors() {
        this.charttitle = "Sector Distribution";
        this.apidata = [
            ['APP Android', 45.0],
            ['APP Ios', 26.8],
            ['Widget Web', 12.8],
            ['MTC BAckoffice', 8.5],
            ['Correo electrónico', 6.2],
            ['Facebook', 6.2],
            ['Twitter', 6.2],
            ['Teléfono', 6.2],
            ['Presencial', 6.2],
        ];
        this.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true,
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                    height: 135,
                    width: 160,
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    useHTML: true,
                    labelFormatter: function () {
                        return '<div style="text-align: left; width:120px;float:left;">' + this.name + '  ' + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%</div>';
                    },
                    itemStyle: {
                        color: '#421C40',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontFamily: 'Century Gothic',
                        fontSize: '10px'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> Weight: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
            },
            title: {
                text: this.charttitle,
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Weight',
                size: '75%',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: this.apidata
            }],
            loading: false
        }
    }

    function ipomarketcap() {
        this.charttitle = "Market Cap Distribution";
        this.apidata = [
            ['MC APP Android', 45.0],
            ['MC APP Ios', 26.8],
            ['MC Widget Web', 12.8],
            ['MC MTC BAckoffice', 8.5],
            ['MC Correo electrónico', 6.2],
            ['MC Facebook', 6.2],
            ['MC Twitter', 6.2],
            ['MC Teléfono', 6.2],
            ['MC Presencial', 6.2],
        ];
        this.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true,
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                    height: 135,
                    width: 160,
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    useHTML: true,
                    labelFormatter: function () {
                        return '<div style="text-align: left; width:120px;float:left;">' + this.name + '  ' + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%</div>';
                    },
                    itemStyle: {
                        color: '#421C40',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontFamily: 'Century Gothic',
                        fontSize: '10px'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> Weight: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
            },
            title: {
                text: this.charttitle,
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Weight',
                size: '75%',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: this.apidata
            }],
            loading: false
        }
    }

    function BindingCode($scope, Factory) {

        $scope.iposectors = Factory.CreatePieChart('iposectors');
        debugger;
    }

    function Factory() {
        return {
            CreatePieChart: function (type) {
                if (type == 'iposectors') {
                    return new iposectors();
                }
                else {
                    return new ipomarketcap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

html page

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myctrl">
            @*<highchart id="chart1" config="highchartsNG"></highchart>*@
            <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="span9"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data is binded to `iposectors` property, while highcharts-ng expects config in `$scope` variable. For example you can bind this references this way:

```
function BindingCode($scope, Factory) {

    $scope.iposectors = Factory.CreatePieChart('iposectors');
    $scope.chartConfig = $scope.iposectors.chartConfig;

}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fjv93vvu/

Comment: Thank you Pawel, it worked perfectly. Here is the updated fiddle with both pie charts showing: https://jsfiddle.net/ksutine/4774vmcs/